# Codeigniter site was not working in live server

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, http

Can someone help me,

My site was working fine in staging server and I moved the site live server where I am getting HTTP ERROR 500.

My htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

The same htaccess file was there in both the servers. mod_rewrite was enabled and everything was fine from server side. Can someone help me what can be the issue

Comment: What does `/var/log/apache2/error.log` say?

Comment: CI works without special  `.htaccess` files.

Comment: What are the permissions on your root folder? Last time I had this issue it was that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly an answer but too large for a comment:

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT) {
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(~E_DEPRECATED);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        break;
    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        error_reporting(~E_DEPRECATED);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        break;
    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
        exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}
```

Change `production` to have the same error_reporting as `development` so you will get the errors instead of seeing a generic 500 page.

I don't believe you .htaccess file is at fault here as you wouuld get a 400 rather than a 500 (internal server error).

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try this:

upload htaccess file in root

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    Options -Indexes


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
      </IfModule>

        <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```